# How to plot a Horizontal bar with y-axis value from categorical data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pivot-table, bar-chart

The organization is the index and I need to show a horizontal bar plot showing the total number of attempts of experiments conducted by each organization, with the most at the top and the fewest at the bottom.

The data frame are as follows :
Organization  DateTime  Attempts
a            ....      Failed
b            ....      Success
b            ....      Failed
a            ....      Partial Success
a            ....      Success
b            ....      Partial Success

I got the idea that the attempts is categorical data and it has some `count_values()` function but
just don't know how to code it?

[image: sampledataset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume this input:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 50),
                   'Location': 'non-relevant',
                   'Outcome': np.random.choice(['Success', 'Failure'], 50),
                  }).set_index('company')
df.head()
```

```
             Location  Outcome
company                       
A        non-relevant  Success
D        non-relevant  Failure
B        non-relevant  Failure
A        non-relevant  Failure
D        non-relevant  Failure
...
```

Calculate the counts per group and sort:

```
>>> df2 = df.groupby('company')['Outcome'].count().sort_values()
>>> df2
company
C     8
A    12
B    12
D    18
Name: Outcome, dtype: int64
```

plot:

```
df2.plot.barh()
```

[image: barh]

And here how to calculate with failure/successes:

```
df2 = df.groupby('company')['Outcome'].value_counts().unstack('Outcome')
df2 = df2.loc[df2.sum(axis=1).sort_values().index]
df2.plot.barh(stacked='True')
```

[image: barh stacked]

Comment: 1. You can edit your question and add the content of df2 + graph. 2. Do you want to ignore the "partial" values or consider them as success/failure? (e.g. partial success -> success)